# WebView Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando cargar una página web y me funciona perfecta mi aplicación.
El problema lo tengo en que la web tiene una cabecera que me gustaría ocultar es el dato siguiente:

Como puedo hacer para ocultarlo??

```
<div id="progression-sticky-header" class="" style="z-index: auto; position: static; top: auto;">           <header id="masthead-pro" class="progression-studios-site-header progression-studios-nav-left">
                <div id="progression-studios-sidebar-sticky-header">                    
                    <div id="logo-nav-pro">

                        <div class="width-container-pro progression-studios-logo-container">
                            <h1 id="logo-pro" class="logo-inside-nav-pro noselect"> <a href="https://hotelvader.top/" title="Hotel Vader" rel="home">       



            <img src="https://hotelvader.top/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo_main_menu.png" alt="Hotel Vader" class="progression-studios-default-logo   ">

        </a>
</h1>
                        </div><!-- close .width-container-pro -->



    <div class="width-container-pro optional-centered-area-on-mobile">

    <nav id="progression-studios-right-navigation">
    <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
    </nav>

        <div class="mobile-menu-icon-pro noselect"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>

        <div id="progression-studios-header-search-icon" class="noselect">
            <i class="pe-7s-search"></i>
            <div id="panel-search-progression">
                <form method="get" class="search-form" action="https://hotelvader.top/">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Enter keyword to search the site..." value="" name="s">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
</form><div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="progression-inline-icons">
<div class="progression-studios-social-icons">

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HotelVader/" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-facebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/HotelVader" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-twitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hotelvader/" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-instagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a> <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/4qwpo6i9exd35y8ldr6bzrvc4?si=tVHsuAcjQOWrB_g9mRxhhA" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-spotify" title="Spotify"><i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a>   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-KLbHw05hg-t-yPu9PtxPw" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-youtube" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></a>                                             



    <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
</div><!-- close .progression-studios-social-icons --></div>        
        <div id="progression-nav-container">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows" style="touch-action: pan-y;"><li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-828"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/podcasts/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Podcasts</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-555"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/comics/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Cómics</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-554"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/videojuegos/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Videojuegos</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-556"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/cine-y-series/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Cine y Series</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-557"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/rock-and-roll/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Rock and Roll</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-553"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/juegos-de-mesa/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Juegos de mesa</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1153"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/libros/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Libros</span></a></li>
</ul></div><div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
            </nav>
            <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
        </div><!-- close #progression-nav-container -->



        <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
    </div><!-- close .width-container-pro -->



                    </div><!-- close #logo-nav-pro -->

        <div id="main-nav-mobile">

            <div class="progression-studios-social-icons">

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HotelVader/" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-facebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>             <a href="https://twitter.com/HotelVader" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-twitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hotelvader/" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-instagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>             <a href="https://open.spotify.com/user/4qwpo6i9exd35y8ldr6bzrvc4?si=tVHsuAcjQOWrB_g9mRxhhA" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-spotify" title="Spotify"><i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a>               <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-KLbHw05hg-t-yPu9PtxPw" target="_blank" class="progression-studios-youtube" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></a>                                                                                                                                                                                 


                <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
            </div><!-- close .progression-studios-social-icons -->

                            <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><div class="menu-collapser" style="display: none;">Menu<div class="collapse-button"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></div></div><ul id="menu-main-navigation-1" class="mobile-menu-pro" style="display: block;"><li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-828"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/podcasts/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Podcasts</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-555"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/comics/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Cómics</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-554"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/videojuegos/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Videojuegos</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-556"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/cine-y-series/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Cine y Series</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-557"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/rock-and-roll/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Rock and Roll</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-553"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/juegos-de-mesa/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Juegos de mesa</span></a></li>
<li class="normal-item-pro  menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1153"><a href="https://hotelvader.top/index.php/libros/"><span class="progression-studios-menu-title">Libros</span></a></li>
</ul></div>                     
            <div class="sidebar progression-studios-mobile-sidebar"></div>

            <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
        </div><!-- close #mobile-menu-container -->             
                </div><!-- close #progression-studios-sidebar-sticky-header -->         </header>
        </div>
```

El código de la app es:

```
  WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.miVisor);
        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(url);


class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

Me faltaría saber como no extraer la parte de una página web.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es pasar una variable en la URL que utilices para detectar que estás cargando la web desde la app y en ese caso no se muestra el encabezado.

Por ejemplo:

```
url = url + "?isapp=1";
view.loadUrl(url);
....
```

Y si tu web está en PHP:

```
if (!$_REQUEST["isapp"]) {
//Aquí el encabezado
}
```

Si no existe esa variable no se mostrará. También puedes poner el encabezado y en caso de que exista la variable añadir un `display none`.

Comment: hola carmen la web es www.hotelvader.top si entras dentro verás que hay un encabezado que me gustaría que no saliera. Voy algo perdida con el tema sinceramente. Pruebo la opción 1  a ver si me funciona